# How to define default values in typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

When defining a custom type in Typescript I'd like to say that if an inner element is not defined then a default value is going to be used.

so for example:

```
function custom(a:{required:string, optional='haha'}) {

}
```

This does not work :(

I cannot use `type` since that syntax is not working either. It would be nice to find the correct syntax to be used.

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript supports this, I think code will explain it best:

```
//You can set defaults for variables
var defaultingString: string = "Default"

//You can create custom types through classes
var myCustomType: TestClass;
class TestClass {
    //You can set defaults for variables in classes too
    testVarA: string = "Default";

    //You can handle it in a class constructor
    //(which can also have defaults in it's parameters)
    testVarB: string;
    constructor(public someParam: string = "DefaultParam") {
        if (!this.testVarB){
            this.testVarB = someParam;
        }
    }

    //Works in regular functions both for parameters and return type
    testFoo (someOtherParam: string = this.testVarA): string {
        return someOtherParam;
    }
}
```

Paste into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ and play around :)

Comment: myCustomType is not usable. Plus hte problem is within destructuring :(